# Ciclos anidados en C

Tags: bucles, clase-anidada

¿Como puedo hacer un programa que por ejemplo si el usuario escribe el numero 1234 el programa muestre: "Tu numero esta formado por el 1 por el 2 por el 3 y por el 4"?
el chiste es que el programa muestre en pantalla cada dígito que forma al numero.
Intenté algo asi pero lo unico que logre fue que imprimiera por el 1 por el 12 y por el 123 insertando el 123 claro.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    int cifras=1,cifras1,cifras2,cifras3;
    int long a,a1;
    printf("Introduce un entero de cualquier cantidad de digitos: ");
    scanf("%ld",&a);
    printf("Tu numero esta formado  ");
    a1=a;
    while(a>=10){
        a/=10;
    cifras++;}
    while(cifras>0){
    cifras3=cifras;
    printf("por el %ld",a1);
    cifras1=cifras-1;
    cifras2=cifras-1;
    for(cifras1;cifras1>0;cifras1--){
        printf("\b");}
    for(cifras2;cifras2>0;cifras2--){
        printf(" ");}
    cifras--;}
}
```

Comment: Hola. Lo que necesitas es tener una función que separe la cadena, caracter por caracter. Una función similar a charAt de Java.

Comment: En vez de pedir el dato como tipo entero, hazlo como tipo "string". De ese modo puedes imprimir dígito por dígito.

Answer (score 2):

Como han puesto en los comentarios, este problema se resuelve más fácil con cadenas, pero si tuvieras que hacerlo OBLIGATORIAMENTE con valores numéricos, una forma sencilla puede ser la siguiente:

Ejemplo: **5347**
1- Calcular la cantidad de dígitos que tiene una cifra. La forma más fácil de hacer esto es usando el `logaritmo de base 10`, el cual puede servir para saber la cantidad de dígitos - 1.

> log10(10) = 1 || log10(100) = 2 || log10(100000) = 5 || log10(9999) = 3.9999

Entonces:
`num_digit = log10(5342) = 3.728`. La parte entera: `3`

Dentro del ciclo `for`
2- iniciar el `for` decreciente desde `num_digit` hasta `0`
3- `potencia = 10^i = 10^3 = 1000`
4- `residuo = 5347 % 1000 = 347`
5- `digito = (5347 - 347) / 1000 = 5000 / 1000 = 5` (Se imprime este valor)
6- Se le asigna el valor del residuo `a = 347`
Se repite el ciclo ahora con el nuevo valor de `a`

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (){
    int num_digits, i;
    int long a, digito, potencia, residuo;
    printf("Introduce un entero de cualquier cantidad de digitos: ");
    scanf("%ld",&a);
    num_digits = log10(a);
    for(i=num_digits; i>=0; i--) {
        potencia = pow(10, i);
        residuo = fmod(a, potencia);
        digito = (a - residuo) / potencia;
        printf("Tu numero esta formado por %ld\n", digito);
        a = residuo;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Nota: `a` debe ser `> 0`

Answer (score 0):

C te permite el uso de punteros, y estos pueden llegar a ser demasiado utiles a la hora de iterar sobre un arreglo de caracteres.

```c
int main() {


    /* Aqui lo que haces, es primeramente obtener la entrada del usuario,
       utilizamos fgets() para nuestro proposito. 
    */
    char buffer[255];
    fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);

    /* Ahora, para poder "iterar" sobre la cadena, "necesitamos" un puntero */
    char *numero = buffer;

    /* Aquí es dónde ocurre todo, lo que hace, es incrementar el puntero después
      de imprimir nuestro texto, apunta al caracter siguiente en nuestro buffer.
       Y se detiene si encuentra una línea nueva, (esto sucede al ingresar los datos
      en fgets() y presionar 'enter') */

    while(*numero != '\n') {
        printf("Tu numero esta formado por %c\n", *numero++);
    }


    return 0;
```

Recuerda notar, que siempre la entrada del usuario es un arreglo de caracteres!

Mucha suerte!